# LibGDX drawing circles scales somehow

Tags: java, libgdx, image-scaling

I try to draw 2 circles using textures in Java with LibGDX.
My classes are pretty straightforward, GameObject has a circle (for logic) and a draw method.

Here is my draw method:

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
    batch.draw(sprite, circle.x-circle.radius, circle.y-circle.radius, circle.x+circle.radius, circle.y+circle.radius);
}
```

This is the code I execute:

```
GameObject go = new GameObjectBuilder().createNew()
                .withPosition(32, 32)
                .withRadius(32)
                .withTexture(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ball.png")))
                .withId(0)
                .build();

GameObject go2 = new GameObjectBuilder().createNew()
            .withPosition(64, 64)
            .withRadius(32)
            .withTexture(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ball.png")))
            .withId(1)
            .build();

stage.addActor(go);
stage.addActor(go2);
```

And this is the result:
[image: Strange scaling on the balls]

Somehow using circles with the same size, scales them when placed further away from the origin. Currently my main class extends ApplicationAdapter and that's it.

Here is the stack of calls I make in my builder.

```
circle.setPosition(x, y); // LibGDX.Circle class call
circle.setRadius(radius); // LibGDX.Circle class call
sprite = new Sprite(texture);
```

Using a ShapeRenderer, calling the same objects and drawing a filled circle yields these results:

```
shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);

for(GameObject goo : objects.values()) {
    shapeRenderer.circle(goo.getX(), goo.getY(), goo.getRadius());
}

shapeRenderer.end();
```

[image: black balls on top]

Final edit:

```
batch.draw(sprite, circle.x-circle.radius, circle.y-circle.radius, circle.radius*2, circle.radius*2);
```

Did the trick!

Comment: Have you tried hard coding the values for width and height into your `batch.draw()` call? Does that give the expected behaviour?

Comment: I should add that Michael Hobbs' answer should do the trick, that is where your problem lies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been a while since I used libGDX and I can tell some things have changed. However...

```
void draw(TextureRegion region,
      float x,
      float y,
      float width,
      float height)
```

Draws a rectangle with the bottom left corner at x,y and stretching the region to cover the given width and height.

Batch.draw draws a rectangle from x,y to x + width, y + height. What you have done is to scale the shape based on the objects internal position.

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
    batch.draw(sprite, circle.x-circle.radius, circle.y-circle.radius, circle.x+circle.radius, circle.y+circle.radius);
}
```

for circle 1 we have
    batch.draw(sprite, 32-32, 32-32, 32+32, 32+32);
This draws the sprite from 0,0 to 64,64

for circle 2 we have
    batch.draw(sprite, 64-32, 64-32, 64+64, 64+64);
This draws the sprite from 32,32 to 128,128

This should fix your code:

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
    batch.draw(sprite, circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius, circle.radius);
}
```

This will scale the objects base on the circle's radius.

Reference: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Batch.html#draw-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture-float-float-float-float-

Comment: I updated the question with the actual calls that are made to the GameObject. I just use the Circles setPosition and setRadius.

Comment: tried that, it just draws HUGE circles which are unscaled... This is the result: http://i.imgur.com/RfBKC23.png

Comment: One of the things I did in my libGDX project to help me debug my sprites was to add in a chunk of code that showed where the sprite was drawn from.

    public void drawAnchorPoints(ShapeRenderer sr) {
        sr.setAutoShapeType(true);
        sr.setColor(Color.RED);
        sr.begin();
        for (Entry<String, Vector2> vec : anchorPoints.entrySet()) {
            Vector2 temp = vec.getValue().cpy().add(getPosition(););
            sr.line(temp.x - 2, temp.y, temp.x + 2, temp.y);
            sr.line(temp.x, temp.y - 2, temp.x, temp.y + 2);
        }
        sr.end();
    }

Comment: Ok, I remember now what the problem is. Give me a bit looking through my project for how I fixed this issues.

The sprite is being drawn based on the originals texture size this is why you get the big balls.

Comment: Looking at my old project I belive the issues is that you are not setting the width and height of the sprites. Sprite.spriteWidth and Sprite.spriteHeight. With out these set the texture will be draw at it's native size.

Comment: Thanks. I finally found the error (was a sneaky one!)

Comment: Glad to hear. I'm going to rebuild my old project and drop it on github latter. It should give you some idea's. I have to rebuild/import all the code as I screwed up my gradle beyond repair. ;)